# PyQt5 only child item clicked

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

My question is:
I have a QListWidget with items(on the left side of window) and QTextEdit on the right

```
items               textEdit 
-item1
---subitem1
---subitem2
-item2
---subitem1
---subitem2
```

I fill the listWidget like this:

```
for name in names:
        item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([name])
        self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(item)
        for cmd in description:
            item2 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([cmd])
            item.addChild(item2)
```

Then i want that if i cklicked on subitems some text appears in textEdit
Only subitems can appear text.
I wrote

```
self.treeWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.item2Clicked)
....
def item2Clicked(self, item, column):
    self.textEdit.insertPlainText("hello")
```

But it's not right, because if i click on the item1 - text appears too.
Thanks for your help and sorry for my english:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top-level items don't have a parent, so you could do:

```
    def item2Clicked(self, item, column):
        if item.parent() is not None:
            self.textEdit.insertPlainText("hello")
```

More generally, you can set a [type](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#type) for each item in the constructor:

```
    item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([name], 1)
    self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(item)
    for cmd in description:
        item2 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([cmd], 2)
```

and then do:

```
    def item2Clicked(self, item, column):
        if item.type() == 2:
            self.textEdit.insertPlainText("hello")
```